# public passwords in github

Tags: wordpress, git, github

my wordpress website is on my laptop with a lot of older versions in it using Git.

Until today, I've had my own Git server but now I would like to push the repository into Github. So I have edit the `.gitignore` file to ignore the `wp-config.php` and avoid having my database passwords opened to everyone, but when I push my repository I can see on github the older versions of this file.

**Is there any way to completely ignore any version of this file when I push to github?**

Comment: **Whatever** you do, don't [do this](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:github.com+master/wp_config.php+password+blob+DB_PASSWORD&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS476US476&oq=site:github.com+master/wp_config.php+password+blob+DB_PASSWORD&aqs=chrome.0.57j58.483&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and maybe follow [this guy example](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton/blob/master/wp-config.php), saludos ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `git filter-branch` to modify your whole history, removing the `wp-config.php` file from the repository. See the [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) for an example.